# dlopen on new binary with same name returns old handle

Tags: c++, dlopen, dynamic-library

I'm using dlopen to load dynamically generated code. The program calls the compiler on the code and generates a .so file which is then loaded by the program to extend itself.

The problem is that if I use the same name for the generated code, the dlopen returns a handle to the old object, not the new one.

The code looks like:

```
…generate code into test.cpp
system("gcc <args> test.cpp -o test.so");
void *handle = dlopen("test.so");
void *sym = dlsym(handle, "run");
(*sym)();
dlclose(handle);
…Do other work
…generate different code to test.cpp
system("gcc <args> test.cpp -o test.so");
void *handle = dlopen("test.so");
void *sym = dlsym(handle, "run");
(*sym)();
<crash here because the code isn't what was expected>
```

Is this a basic flaw in `dlopen`'s cache code or something well known and not well documented in `dlopen`?

Comment: What flags are you using to dlopen? Is the path relative/absolute or just the filename? Are you 100% sure you're dlclos'ing the handle?

Comment: You might need to identify which platform you're working on — I suspect Linux, but you might need to be more precise than that (it covers a lot of different systems).  You might need to produce an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Do you check that you get a valid response from `dlsym()` before using what it returns?

Comment: Linux and MacOS X both act the same. We are passing dlopen("/tmp/example.so", RTLD_NOW); Always an absolute path. Each dlopen is matched to a dlclose. There are no other calls to dlopen. dlsym always returns a valid address. The problem is that the address isn't from the new code, rather it is from the old code. We use the same entry point "run" for all our generated code.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to use a randomly-generated output filename. `dlclose` is a fundamentally impossible-to-implement function.

Comment: Maybe the answer is not to use the same entry point name each time but to create a unique name for the function (use a random number: `char entry_point[32]; snprintf(entry_point, sizeof(entry_point), "run_%d", rand());` and use that as the function name, both in the generated code and in the call to `dlsym()`.  And maybe create a different shared object name each time, too – you could use the same random number (if you capture it) as part of the shared object name.

Comment: @o11c Why impossible?

Comment: @PaulSanders Because `dlsym` isn't the only thing inspecting its guts. Internal machinery also grabs pointers, e.g. for the PLT.

Comment: @o11c Not wanting to hijack this thread, but would that be a problem, if the library was only accessed via `dlopen` and `dlsym`?  From the comments to the answer below, it sounds like the OP is now calling `dlclose` successfully (and I'm interested because I do something very similar in my own app - because LAME is not re-entrant).

Comment: @PaulSanders my problem was specific to c++, the GNU_UNIQUE symbols and linking with a static libstdc++. If you are using generic 'C' this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probly `dlclose` failed to unload the library. This usually happens when it contains [GNU_UNIQUE symbols](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826567) (which tend to sneak in if you link with static libstdc++). This can be verified via

```
$ readelf -sW --dyn-syms path/to/libxyz.so | grep '\bUNIQUE\b'
...
3808: 0000000000302e78     8 OBJECT  UNIQUE DEFAULT   27 _ZNSt8messagesIcE2idE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```

To fix this, you can try one of the following:

- build library with `-fvisibility=hidden` and `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to hide unique symbols
- build with `-Wl,--version-script` to achieve the same
- build shlib with toolchain that was configured with `--disable-gnu-unique-object` (see [discussion in GCC list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-01/msg00008.html))

Comment: We are using c++ and this appears to be the issue.

Comment: @DavidBarto I've added some suggestions on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: And with the addition of -fvisibility=hidden and explicitly making our 'run' symbol public, the problem is solved. Thanks yugr!

Comment: @DavidBarto Np, you might want to accept the answer if it was helpful.