# dlopen(RTLD_NOLOAD) still returns not null after dlclose

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen

I am writing a function to check if a .so is loaded under linux with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

bool isLibraryLoaded(const string& libPath)
{
   return (nullptr != dlopen(libPath.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_NOLOAD));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   const string libPath = "/path/to/library.so";

   cout << "loaded: " << isLibraryLoaded(libPath) << endl;

   sleep(8); // first execution of lsof

   // load lib
   void* handle = dlopen(libPath.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
   cout << "handle: " << handle << endl;
   if (nullptr != handle)
   {
      cout << "loaded: " << isLibraryLoaded(libPath) << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "error: " << dlerror() << endl;
   }

   sleep(8); // second execution of lsof

   // unload lib
   if (0 == dlclose(handle))
   {
      cout << "loaded: " << isLibraryLoaded(libPath) << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "error: " << dlerror() << endl;
   }

   sleep(8); // third execution of lsof

   return 0;
}
```

output of the program:

```
loaded: 0
handle: 0x6420b0
loaded: 1
loaded: 1
```

first execution of lsof:

```
# lsof /path/to/library.so
(return -1)
```

second execution of lsof:

```
# lsof /path/to/library.so
COMMAND  PID   USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
test    3240     me mem    REG   8,33 333493040 5242954 /path/to/library.so
```

third execution of lsof:

```
# lsof /path/to/library.so
COMMAND  PID   USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
test    3240     me mem    REG   8,33 333493040 5242954 /path/to/library.so
```

The program is very simple, the library should be loaded and unloaded again.  But it is NOT. I am very confusing and have the following questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my code?
2. Why does dlclose() not really unload the library?
3. What could be the potential reasons?
4. Is there any way for C/C++ to detect if a library is loaded/unloaded?

My environment:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1~16.04) 6.4.0 20180424
```

Comment: Perhaps `RTLD_NOLOAD` is not being honoured.  It's documented as needing glibc 2.2 - do you have that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dlopen on new binary with same name returns old handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437892/dlopen-on-new-binary-with-same-name-returns-old-handle)

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
bool isLibraryLoaded(const string& libPath)
{
   return (nullptr != dlopen(libPath.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_NOLOAD));
}
```

is wrong because IFF the library is already loaded (i.e. if the function returns `true`), then the handle reference count is incremented by `dlopen`. You need a matching `dlclose` to undo that increment.

Here is the fixed version:

```
bool isLibraryLoaded(const string& libPath)
{
   void *h = dlopen(libPath.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_NOLOAD);
   if (h != nullptr) {
     dlclose(h);
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

With that fix:

```
$ ./a.out
loaded: 0
handle: 0x19382a0
loaded: 1
loaded: 0
```

Comment: Nice answer.  [Documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) sadly deficient.

Answer (score 0):

`dlclose` is often a no-op.

To anwser your question: Why does dlclose() not really unload the library? This is rather complicated. It could because of many different reasons. One thing you may want to know is GCC's "-fno-gnu-unique" option. I do not suggest using it. You should know why the option exists:

`On systems with recent GNU assembler and C library, the C++ compiler uses the STB_GNU_UNIQUE binding to make sure that definitions of template static data members and static local variables in inline functions are unique even in the presence of RTLD_LOCAL; this is necessary to avoid problems with a library used by two different RTLD_LOCAL plugins depending on a definition in one of them and therefore disagreeing with the other one about the binding of the symbol. But this causes dlclose to be ignored for affected DSOs`

The right solution is to build a C API for every C++ library and use a linker version script.
A sample version script is like:

```
VERS_1.0 {
  global:
    MyFunc1;
    MyFunc2;
    MyFunc3;
  local:
    *;
};
```

MyFunc1/MyFunc2/MyFunc3 are C-style public APIs exported from your library.

Then you add `-Wl,--version-script=/path/to/the_above_file` to the link command of the library.  This is crucial to make the `dlcose` work!!!